# How to use PHP withouth reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I have the following files with their respective code:

#### Controler.php

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" style="display:none"></iframe>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('frame1').src='Create.php'">Create</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('frame2').src='Drop.php'">Drop</button>
```

#### Create.php

```
<?php
  mysqli_query(new mysqli('localhost','root'),'create database `db1`')
?>
```

#### Drop.php

```
<?php
  mysqli_query(new mysqli('localhost','root'),'drop database `db1`')
?>
```

What they do is, make a `button` that creates a database when clicked and another one that deletes that same database (named `db1`). My problem is getting it to work without having to reload the page.

Comment: Please take a second look to AJAX, that's what you need.

Comment: No Page refresh = AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use AJAX. Onclick you can send a xmlhttprequest (JS) to a separate php file, which is executed.

Example:

```
function test()
  {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","your_ajax_file.php",true);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

your_ajax_file.php can create / drop the database.

Comment: How would I implement that into the code, is it just pasting this function on the Controler.php inside `script` tags?

Comment: Yes. Then you can execute this function with onclick event.